# Delphi XE3 - F1062 File not found - package dcu file

Tags: delphi, components

Firstly this is not desperate as I've already worked round it.
I just have a nagging doubt I've done it incorrectly.
I am using Delphi at home (for fun ?).
In Delphi 2006 I replaced all my components with procedures and functions (the free version restricted component registration).
This year I bought a version of XE3 and have just started re-implementing the components.
After successfully creating a package and registering a component I added it to a form.
I got the error message -

F1062 File not found nafMessageDlg.dcu

After a quick browse (of previous answers on this site) I added the file path to the Tools|Options|Environment Options|Delphi Options|Library|Library Path.

And my Test form compiles and works fine.

My question is can this be the correct resolution, if I create thirty components will I need to add thirty paths (or copy all the dcu files to one folder and add that path). I just feel I must have missed a trick here.

All the best, Nick

Comment: Why don't you add the source .pas files to your project?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. You don't have to keep all your components at different locations though.

Comment: That depends if you build monolithic EXE or modular EXE+BPL mix. In former case you have to have DCUs on path (or sources to recreate DCUs ad hoc), in latter on path should be DCPs. Standard Delphi RTL and VCL registers paths to both DCPs and DCUs for both compilation modes to work.